# Partial Tag in Razor ASP.Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using `Partial tag helper` (Renders the partial view **asynchronously**.) for my Razor Pages Web app project.

**Problem:**
I have a page (.cshtml) where i need to show some data (using partial tag helper for this) to the user, followed by a button for submission if the data is correct. What is happening is, button is being rendered first (going out of alignment) then data appears few seconds after.... I want data to be shown first then followed by any UI controls

**My question is:**

1. how to render view synchronously using the `partial tag` ? or how to wait for the view to complete the rendering.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what problem is being caused by this asynchronous rendering you refer to?

Comment: I have a page (.cshtml) where i need to show some data (using partial tag helper for this) to the user, followed by a button for submission if the data is correct. What is happening is, button is being rendered first (going out of alignment) then data appears few seconds after.... I want data to be shown first then followed by any UI controls.

Comment: What you describe doesn't sound like it will be caused by using a partial taghelper. There is something else entirely going on there. While the partial taghelper works asynchronously, the content is merged into the Razor page _before_ it is sent to the browser. Your description sounds more like you are fetching data asynchronously _after_ the page has been rendered to the browser i.e. using AJAX. Is that the case?

Comment: @MikeBrind: Yes you are spot on..I thought the `partial tag` is the problem. The Problem is caused by as you correctly guessed is because of AJAX call there. I think i will be able to solve. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is no synchronous option with the partial tag helper. You can use the `Html.Partial` or `Html.RenderPartial` helpers to force synchronous execution instead.